# Does $ \langle x, x \rangle = \langle y,y \rangle $ imply $ \| x \| = \| y \|. $

Tags: vectors, normed-spaces, inner-products

Does $ \langle x, x \rangle = \langle y,y \rangle $ imply $ \| x \| = \| y \|. $

Since $ \langle x, x \rangle = \| x \|^2 $ we have $$ \langle x, x \rangle = \langle y,y \rangle $$ is equivalent to $$ \|  x \|^2 = \| y\|^2. $$ Am I able to claim that this implies $$ \| x \| = \| y \|$$ since $\| x \| \geq 0?$

Comment: yes, and you even used the right reasoning, so there's no faults in your arguement

Comment: Zed1.$||x||^2-||y||^2=0$; $(||x||-||y||)(||x||+||y||)=0$;If the second factor $=0$: $||x||=||y||=0$,all is well.If the second factor $\not =0$, what then?